# Why stringstream::str() truncates string?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream, boost-iostreams

I have stringstream object. It is filled through

```
stringstream ss;
boost::iostreams::copy(inp,ss);
```

from

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> inp;
```

and actually holds ungzipped file within.

Now if i flush stringstream content to file with

```
std::ofstream ofs(path_to_file,std::ios_base::out|std::ios_base::binary);
ofs << ss.rdbuf();
```

everything is ok. File is filled with complete correct data.

But if i instead of flushing to file construct string like this

```
std::string s = ss.str();
```

content is truncated somewhere in the middle. It is not a persistent error, and it obviously depends on content of string buffer.

The content is HTML file in several languages.

What can it be? Thanks.

Comment: Because null-terminating characters are treated differently in the two situations. (probably)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you determining that the content is truncated?  A `stringstream` can contain null characters and `std::string s = ss.str()` will copy those null characters and the characters after it to the `std::string` object.

However, if you then use functions that treat the `std::string` object's contents as a C style string, it will appear truncated:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

stringstream ss;

int main()
{
    ss << 'a' << 'b' << 'c' << (char) '\0' << '1' << '2' << '3';

    string s = ss.str();

    cout << s.size() << endl;
    cout << s.c_str() << " C string length: " << strlen(s.c_str()) << endl;
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

produces the following output:

```
7
abc C string length: 3
abc 123
```

Comment: Michael, the cast to `char` of `'\0'` is unnecessary - it's already a character literal.  Also worth noting in output on a terminal - there's no visible separation of "abc123". However, if you redirect the output to a file, you'll see the null in a hex dump. (Still got my upvote).

Comment: I can see in debugger, that string is definitely truncated.

Comment: If you're using the VS debugger, the basic string display is probably lying to you - the debugger display of `std::string` (and, as an FYI, of .NET string objects) will stop at a null character even if the object contains more data. Try stepping through my example program - the debugger displays "abc" for the value of `s`, even though `s.size()` and the last line of the program clearly indicate there is more. Also, you can expand the display (click the '+' next to the variable name in the debugger display) and it will list each element of the string - including the null characters.

Comment: Yes you were right, actual string is complete, debugger displays incorrectly.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that this debugger 'quirk' hasn't been fixed. I guess not a lot of people run into it, so there aren't a lot of complaints. But when you go get hit by it, it can really throw your debugging session into the weeds.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have null character symbol '\0' in your file. That considered as end of string.

Comment: This is not correct: `std::string` is not null-terminated. Yes, it's true that the very last character is null (for C compatibility), but it allows for embedded nulls.  `strlen(s.c_str())` is not necessarily the same as `s.size()`.

Comment: agree, std::string is not, but C-string is a null-terminated sequence of characters